# Is charge density zero in a dielectric material and why?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm trying to solve a problem involving parallel capacitor. I can't decide whether to use poisson's formula or laplace's formula.

[image]

The question is, is there $\rho_v$ in a piece of dielectric and why?

Comment: You can add a diagram to show us if you are considering? Maybe we can provide an accurate answer.

Comment: In a capacitor, charge in = charge out. So there is no mechanism for putting a net charge on the dielectric. It is of course possible to charge a dielectric (think glass rods and silk cloths) but there you need to "pull away" the charge from one object to another. When the capacitor is in a circuit, such a one way path does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The charge density in the bulk of the dielectric is zero, but the net result of the electric polarization is that charge builds up on the surfaces.

You need to include this charge if you use Maxwell's equations for vacuum.  You do *not* need to include this charge if you use Maxwell's equations in a medium, as it is already accounted for.  (This is the version with $D$ and $H$ as well as $E$ and $B$.)

Of course you don't need the whole of Maxwell's equations to solve the problem of the parallel plate capacitor, so long as you know how to modify Gauss's law appropriately for a dielectric.